# Is there a way to set a margin below a sticky header so that scrolled content does not touch the header bottom edge?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I think the subject says it all and also I attached a picture.

[image]

Notice how scrolled content touches the very bottom of the sticky header when content is scrolled. I am trying to change that behavior but not sure how to go about it.

Based on reading other posts on this sort of topic I tried creating another fixed div below the header with white content and high z-index but that didn't work well because the height of the fixed header can change as screen gets narrow.

So I am at a loss for how to ensure there is space under a variable height, fixed header.

Ideas? Maybe I am missing something really simple?

Comment: If you want a visual break between the header and content why not `border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;` or alternatively `box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #fff;`? Obviously substitute your own lengths and colours. There are also alternatives using pseudo-elements and their borders or backgrounds.

Comment: In answer to my question "Maybe I am missing something really simple?" the answer is yes! Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Well, if that answered your question please do write an answer showing your solution and, in a couple of days once you’re able, accept that self-answer (unless a better answer, that you prefer, is posted by someone else between times).

Comment: You can added the margin according to the height of header to body element. Hope this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the answer came from David Thomas in the comments. And it is quite simple!

I just added to my sticky header this:

```
border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
```

So when I said "Maybe I am missing something really simple?" the answer is certainly yes!

Thanks again David.